# Secure communication between a C# client and a PHP Server

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I am maintaining a C# app that's been cracked by people creating spoof auth servers.

I want to encrypt all the communications between the client and server to prevent this happening to my next release.

I can see that PHP has a way to secure stuff.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-decrypt.php

What I can't find is the C# that will allow me to use the same built in libraries.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Did you look into [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx)?